# Scraping map coordinates (Mapbox and leafletjs)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, rvest

I need help with extracting latitudes and longitudes from the map on the following page (scroll down for map) https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P162594
This is the link for just the map https://maps.worldbank.org/?pid=P162594&hideTaskbar=true

I have tried everything with no success. Apparently, they use Leaflet and Mapbox.

Comment: You need to post your code if you want help. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't see any lat or lon coordinates at either of those two links you posted. Maybe you just need to Google for a list of lat & lon coordinates for Columbia, rather than screen scrape for them. Post back if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the network analysis of your browser for the respective request to their API and see if you can replicate it in python or R. Seems to be this one.

```
curl 'https://maps.worldbank.org/gspext-api/rest/postgres/visibleCountries/' -X POST -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Origin: https://maps.worldbank.org' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-GPC: 1' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'TE: trailers' --data-raw '{"level":0,"ccodes":"","polygon":null,"filters":{"proj_stat_name":["Active"]}}'
```